# django - last() and first() return the same object

Tags: python, django

I have two objects in a queryset which is ordered by the created date. I am trying to get the first and last element out of there:

```
ordered = self.get_queryset().order_by('created')
print(ordered)
print(ordered.first(), ordered.last())
```

When running the code, this is the output:

```
<QuerySet [<Item: itemone>, <Item: itemtwo>]>
itemone itemone
```

There are clearly two objects, but for some reason, its giving me the same one.

Btw: I am using SQLite3.

Thanks!

Comment: Does one of these have a `created` is `NULL`?

Comment: Can you provide the (relevant) data of the two objects? I think at least the `created` column is interesting here.

Comment: Nope, the timestamp is present on both of them.

Comment: Oh well, I think I've spotted the error. The problem is that they have the exact same timestamp...

Comment: Seems strange however that it doesn't still return the last element in the queryset.

Comment: Not per se, since note that `.first()` and `.last()` are two queries, and a database does not need to sort the items in case of a tie. Besides being ordered by `created`, the elements can appear random. In case an row is already in memory, it is thus more efficient to return that one, than to perform a more expensive disk operation.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating! But how then did it order the queryset in the first place if the timestamps are the same?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across the same issue using Django 3, `CreateView` class based, and ordering attribute on model class meta. I am not sure why this happens, but `order_by` method fixes the problem.

```py
# only for clarification used last()
GoodModel.objects.order_by().last()
```

#### EDIT:

Apparently the model didn't have any explicit ordering attribute then first as last :) and if you try to paginate you will get clearer warning message.
there are many ways to tell Django model how to deal with ordering like:

```
class UsefulModel(models.Model):
    
    class Meta:
        ordering='-created' # for example
```

hope it is clearer now @Raoul!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with some mock objects - turns out I was sorting on the 'created' timestamp, but since that timestamp was exactly the same for all objects, first() and last() would just always return the same objects.

It's a feature, not a bug:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30901

Fix the issue in this scenario by giving each 'created' field a unique timestamp.

In general, make sure the values you are ordering by are unique.

Comment: That was invalid closed bug !